event.originalEvent.propertyName not working in any none Chromium browsers
jQuery
$('body > header').on('webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(event) { 
                    
    if (event.target && event.originalEvent.propertyName === 'height') {
        console.log('height changed');
    }

});

The CSS is transitioning from height: auto to height: 100% and vise-versa.
This works as expected in Chromium browsers but not in any other browser. In Firefox for example, when I console.log(event.originalEvent.propertyName) before the if parameter I get other property names but never height.
How do I get event.originalEvent.propertyName to return height as Chromium browsers do?
This returns undefined on all browsers:
$('body > header').on('webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(event) { 
    var evt = event.originalEvent || event;
    if (evt.propertyName === 'height') {
         console.log('height changed');
    }
});


It has been true that only Chrome would animate to/from auto for things like "height". Maybe it still is true.

Is there any alternative solution? There MUST be a way to preform this check or a similar one in other browsers...?

Well I understand your frustration, but recall that 10 years ago CSS transitions themselves were fairly exotic. Generally things go slow when the standards committee faces tough questions of how to decide what semantics should be in weird cases.

Sorry, I didn't mean to hit you with the frustration lol I was genuinely just shocked/confused. Thanks for your time.

Currently, some browsers do not support event.originalEvent.propertyName === 'height' when the initial or final CSS property is set to auto. To address this, the best approach is to use CSS's feature detection to apply a static height value for browsers that do not support this behavior. Below is an example implementation:
body > header {
    height: 8.25em;
    transition: height 500ms ease-out;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

    body > header {
        height: 6.25em;
    }

}

/* Styles for Chromium-based browsers (excluding Firefox & Safari) */
@supports (-webkit-appearance: none) and (not (-moz-appearance: none)) and (not (-webkit-touch-callout: none)) {

    body > header {
        height: auto;
    }

}

